# Use a parameterized password in an Execute DDL Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

I have an SSIS package (SQL Server 2016) that includes an Execute DDL Task. The task is to backup a SSAS tabular cube (so it can be replicated on a 2nd server that's on a different domain).

Generally when I write SSIS packages, I parameterize everything that could change over time. In this case, I want to parameterize where I back the file up to as well as the password to use.

In a regular SSIS Script task, I can reference project parameters directly. I don't see any way to do this with an Execute DDL Task. The best I can do is source the entire script from a variable, which then references the parameters in question.

The challenge I have is that I'm working with a password, so I want to mark the password project parameter as sensitive. As soon as I do this, I cannot reference the parameter in a variable.

My options appear to be:

1. Leave the password project parameter not marked as sensitive (meaning it is visible to anyone who opens the package and/or has access to the SSISDB environment variables)
2. Hard-code the script inside the DDL task and not parameterize the password or file name at all. Further, encrypt the entire package (rather than just the sensitive properties) so that anyone who opens the package cannot see it.

The second option sounds the best, since it doesn't involve a password visible in plain text. However, it doesn't allow for any parameterization of the password. (Which means every password change would require a redeployment of the package.)

Have I missed something? Is there another way to reference a parameterized password inside an Execute DDL Task in SSIS that I don't know about? Any other recommendations for this scenario?

Comment: Side note on option 2: I wonder if there could be scenarios where a password contained in plain text inside a variable (in a fully encrypted package) would be included in the ErrorDescription if the script failed to run.

Comment: 2nd Side Note: The documentation on the Execute DDL task does mention that because DDL scripts can contain passwords, the entire package should be encrypted. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/analysis-services-execute-ddl-task

Comment: You can access encrypted parms inside the script task. There is an example of how to do this in the comments generated at the top of the script task. If i have understood your issue correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for referencing a sensitive parameter in an ssis script task:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using the Script task in this instance; I'm using the Execute DDL task.

Comment: Is it possible dynamically generate the DDL statements in a script task prior to the DDL task?

Comment: Have you looked into using this class: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.datatransformationservices.tasks.dtsprocessingtask.asexecuteddltask(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Both good ideas - thank you! I haven't looked at the ASExecuteDDLTask class, but that looks to be a good place to start (since it'd allow me to use the GetSensitiveValue function)